# Understand an existing 'lua' class and inherit from it

Tags: inheritance, lua

I am trying to create a new class which inherits from another class someone else made, but I don't understand the way the class is made, and can't figure out how to make my new class.

Each class is in a seperate `.lua` file.

The base class looks like this:

```
local Base = {}
local function new (_, _type, _subtype)
    local new_base = {}
    local properties = {
    Type = {
        get = function ()
            return _type
        end
        },
    Subtype = {
        get = function ()
            return _subtype
        end
        }
    }

setmetatable( new_base, {
    __index = function (_, key)
        return (properties[key] and properties[key].get()) or Base[key]
    end,
    __newindex = function (_, key, value)
        if properties[key] and properties[key].set then
            properties[key].set( value )
        end
    end,
    } )
return new_base
end

setmetatable( Base, {
__call = new,
} )
return Base
```

Then what I think is a subclass is created from the base class like so:

```
    local Base = require( "vyzor.base" )

    local MiniConsole = Base( "Component", "MiniConsole" )

    local function new (_, name, init_x, init_y, init_width, init_height, word_wrap, font_size)
        local new_console = {}
        <other local variables>

        local function updateAbsolutes ()
            <does stuff>
        end
    local properties = {
    Name = {
        get = function ()
            return name
        end
    },
    Container = {
        get = function ()
            return container
        end,
        set = function (value)
            if value.Type == "Frame" then
                container = value
            end
        end,
                     <and so on>
        end

    function new_console:Echo (text)
         echo( name, text )
     end
    <other functions>

setmetatable( new_console, {
    __index = function (_, key)
        return (properties[key] and properties[key].get()) or MiniConsole[key]
    end,
    __newindex = function (_, key, value)
        if properties[key] and properties[key].set then
            properties[key].set( value )
        end
    end,
    } )
master_list[name] = new_console
return new_console
end

setmetatable( MiniConsole, {
__index = getmetatable(MiniConsole).__index,
__call = new,
} )
return MiniConsole
```

How would I make a class from the MiniConsole class that for example has a new function and variable, and also shares the same properties table from Miniconsole with some more additions:

I think it should start something like this?

```
    local function new(_, name, title, init_x, init_y, init_width, init_height, word_wrap, font_size)
        local new_console = MiniConsole(name, init_x, init_y, init_width, init_height, word_wrap, font_size)
```

Everything I have tried ends up giving me a "circular require or other error" error when I try to pcall it to use it elsewhere.

Comment: What makes you think that `Base` is meant to be used like that, is that a guess or there is actual code somewhere that does this? Seems to me that it should be `Base(A, B)` where `A` and `B` are tables, not strings. Also the whole point of this sort of OO framework is usually to save users the pain of having to define metatables and such, so I'm really surprised that you would have to define another properties table and metatable using it etc. Which library or application is this part of?

Comment: the first two functions are actually in the library, its the third one that I was trying to guess how to use it, so base is definitely used with strings. It is a part of the Vyzor library for mudlet: https://github.com/Oneymus/Vyzor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add functions and data to any table. So you could do

```
function newDerivedMC()
    miniConsole = MiniConsole(...)
    derived = {
        yourData = 1,
        yourMethod = function(self, ...) ... end,
    }
    setmetatable(derived, miniConsole)
    return derived
end

yourMiniConsole = newDerivedMC()
```

If you access a field (data or function) that does not exist in `yourMiniConsole`, interpreter will look in `miniConsole` to see if it exists. If you set a field that does not exist, same thing.